# GNU Make No Message on Missing Phony Targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a sample make file below. When I run `make`, I do not get any message which states that there is no recipe for prerequisite `b`. Is there a way to make it flag this? Without any message, it is misleading that all was good with the command even though `b` did not exist. For missing file prerequisites, we do get an informative message, unlike with phony ones.

```
.PHONY: all a b

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
    
all: a

a: b
  @echo "All good!"
```

Comment: You will get an error if a prerequisite *file* is missing, not if its *rule* is missing. And with a PHONY rule, no file is needed. This is an interesting technical question, but it's hard to think of a use case for it.

Comment: When you declare a target to be `.PHONY` make creates the target internally, so that it can be marked as phony.  So, by writing `.PHONY: b` you've also implicitly declared a target with no prerequisites or recipe, as if you'd written `b:`.  This is not the only way it could work, but this is the way it works today.

Comment: The actual flow is a little more involved with inclusion of nested make files, so `b` would normally be defined in an included file. However, if it is absent for whatever reason, I want to know about it rather than make silently completing.

Comment: A phony target is, by definition, not treated as a file. Therefore, when a target is phony, actual file presence or absence is not considered.